# /usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/en" in any known directory

Tags: linux, dmesg

What exactly does this error mean,

> /usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/en" in any known directory

This is the context,

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 344827 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64_5.10.106-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64 (5.10.106-1) over (5.10.106-1) ...
Setting up linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64 (5.10.106-1) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.10.0-13-amd64:.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64
/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/en" in any known directory
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-13-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-12-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-12-amd64
Found memtest86 image: /memtest86.bin
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
Found memtest86+ multiboot image: /memtest86+_multiboot.bin
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

---

I was originally getting this error on a `dist-upgrade` on a machine with Xorg. I'm writing on the same machine, with I3/Chromium.

However, I can get this error again by running

```
❯ sudo apt-get --reinstall install linux-image-5.10.0-13-amd64
```

Which is how I produced the log, I knew from the context it was installing a kernel image.

Comment: Possibly tangentially related: [Circular dependency in Ubuntu Release upgrade](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202671/circular-dependency-in-ubuntu-release-upgrade)

Comment: @Quasímodo nope, answered in update.